# R6034, but really don't know why

Tags: visual-studio-2005, manifest, visual-c++-2005

I have no problem with Microsoft,but they hate me that's true. I have an application written in Visual Studio 2005,where it's build works fine (VS2005 SP1, Win XP SP3). But I have another PC where I would like to run it. When I try to start it then comes the R6034 error, then I click Retry, then the error comes again, then again Retry and the program starts and works fine.I don't want to see this error message again.

The OS in this PC is Win 7 (64bit). I have installed the required vcredist also.
I have read that I must build my application with a manifest which i have done. I have done the linker one , and I have also  embedded a manifest. I have copied all the requied DLLs from the Visual Studio library with their manifest files into the folder where the exe exists, but still nothing.

I'm really disappointed because I have tried almost everything.Please, if someone know's anything which I can try then help me.If you need more info just tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, now it works. Just remember one thing, the different DLL-s hate themselves.

Comment: I suspect Microsoft have never heard of you, never mind shown any form of contempt for you!

Comment: What did you do to fix it? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: I hope is not so late. The problem was, that the msvcrXX.dll and the other dll files was with the wrong manifest version as the program wanted. In Windows/WinSxs/x86_microsoft.vc80or90.crtORdebugcrt, you pick the one with the same manifest version as your program is, and copy that files into your app folder, if it is in Release than under the Release folder and you copy from the Crt one, if it is Debug than of course the Debug folder and from the DebugCrt one.